# Issues persisting volumes through docker-compose down

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that contains:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres"
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - "/run/postgresql:/run/postgresql:Z"
      - "postgresData:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
volumes:
  postgresData: {}
```

However when I run `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up` the postgres data is lost. From what I understand this is the intended default behavior however I want to change this so my postgres data is never reset. Or maybe I am misunderstanding what `docker-compose down` is for. I see there is also the `stop` and `start` commands but it seems unclear if I can run `docker-compose pull` without running `down`.

How can I make sure that my postgres data is always persisted?

Comment: Are you sure that ``docker-compose down`` removes your volumes? By default, it should only remove containers and networks. Are you specifying the ``-v`` option? Maybe you are looking for something like ``docker-compose up --build --force-recreate``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the curly braces this should work [Official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference)

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres"
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - postgresData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgresData:
```

**docker-compose up**: [offcial-doc up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)
- Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

**docker-compose start**: [offcial-doc start](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/start/)
- Starts existing containers for a service.

**docker-compose down**:[offcial-doc down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)
- Stops containers and removes containers, networks by default, if you want to remove volumes use -v flag

**docker-compose stop**: [offcial-doc stop](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/)
- Stops running containers without removing them. They can be started again with `docker-compose start`